# Unable to find syntax error in mysql query

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, pivot-table

I have got this MySQL pivot table query from somewhere on the internet. I don't remember the URL.

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'max(CASE WHEN ca.date = ''',
      date_format(date, '%Y-%m-%d'),
      ''' THEN coalesce(p.status, ''P'') END) AS `',
      date_format(date, '%Y-%m-%d'), '`'
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM calendar
where date>='2013-06-01'
  and date <= '2013-06-05';

SET @sql 
  = CONCAT('SELECT ca.studentname,
              ca.rollno,
              ca.class, ', @sql, ' 
            from
            (
              select c.date, a.studentname, a.rollno, a.class
              from calendar c
              cross join tbl_admission a
            ) ca
            left join tbl_absentees p
              on ca.rollno = p.rollno
              and ca.date = p.date
            where ca.date>=''2013-06-01''
              and ca.date <= ''2013-06-05''
            group by ca.studentname, ca.rollno, ca.class
            order by ca.rollno');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

When I run this query, then it shows me some syntax errors.
The syntax error is near the

```
'SELECT GROUP_CONCAT'
```

I've tried adding the line but still no  success

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000;
```

Please help me find syntax error in my sql query.

Comment: How are you executing this? This example has 6 SQL statements, but most query interfaces do not allow multi-query. You would need to run each statement in a separate query request (but on the same db connection).

Comment: Thanks for the reply Bill. Before using it in Codeigniter, I'm trying to check the query in PHP myadmin where it's showing me the syntax error. You can try any online MYSQL syntax checker.

Comment: Which phpMyAdmin version are you using? I'm using the latest (5.1.0) and don't see any syntax errors or warnings with your query. It seems likely this was something that's been improved recently in the SQL parsing feature.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Issac. I think you may be right. My phpMyAdmin version is 4.9.2. Let me update my software and check.

Comment: Issac when I visited https://www.wampserver.com/en/ to download the latest version of WAMPserver, there it says that the latest version of phpmyadmin is 4.9.2. Where did you get the latest version(5.1.0) ?

Answer (score 0):

Put it all in a Stored Procedure.

The "near" clause is pointing right at the semicolon or `SELECT`.  So manually try

```
SELECT @sql = NULL;
SELECT 1;
```

If that complains, then you cannot use multiple statements where you are trying to do so.

In that case, either execute each query separately or build a stored proc.

Running the queries separately may run into trouble with `PREPARE`, etc.  So check what is available for your client language.